# list task manager processes in java

Tags: java, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you list all processes on the command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows)

I want to list all processes like "svchost.exe","explorer.exe" of task manager using Java.
If possible, I would also like to know the amount of memory used by each process.

I would prefer a Java-only solution to adapting the command-line answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: Run `tasklist` using `Runtime.exec`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **windows**

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("tasklist.exe"); 
InputStream Outputp = proc.getInputStream ();
if(proc.waitFor () ==0){...//print Outputp}
```

Linux:-

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("ps -A");
```